# TypeScript and Kinetic .on click error

Tags: typescript, kineticjs

I'm getting errors with TypeScript and using the click event on a Kinectic.Text.

Here's my Text:

```
var myButton = new Kinetic.Text({
    // set properties here...
});
```

Here's the problem code:

```
myButton.on('click', function () {
    if (page > 1) {
        renderPage(--page);
        updateButtons();
    }
});
```

This part of the code is underlined saying:

> Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target: Call signatures of types '() => void' and '() => {}' are incompatible

The code that is underlined is:

```
function () {
    if (page > 1) {
        renderPage(--page);
        updateButtons();
    }
});
```

I looked at the Kinectic.d.ts for the .on:

```
on(typesStr: string, handler: () =>{ }): void;
```

I put a : void after the function like:

```
myButton.on('click', function ():  void {
    // same code there
});
```

But now I get a problem with the on myButton.**on**

This error is:

```
Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target: Call signatures of types '() => void' and '() => {}' are incompatible
```

What is causing this error(s)?

Answer (score 1):

Quick fix:

```
myButton.on('click', function () {
    if (page > 1) {
        renderPage(--page);
        updateButtons();
    }
    return {}; // Add this line
});
```

***Explanation:***
The reason is the handler signature:

```
handler: () =>{ }
```

Which is incompatible with the signature of the following function (which is `()=>void`)

```
function () {
    if (page > 1) {
        renderPage(--page);
        updateButtons();
    }
}
```

Since it returns nothing and the compiler has this figured out (first error). Doing:

```
myButton.on('click', function ():  void {
    // same code there
});
```

does not help whatsoever since you are reiterating what the compiler has already inferred (second error).

Return an empty object to make the signature compatible. As I have shown in the quick fix.